# Simplify F-Curves of Shape Key animation

Tags: animation, shape-keys, fcurves, motion-capture

i am trying to clean-up animation curves from facial mocap data. 
The recorded data/animation is containing keys on nearly every frame.

Usually i would use the Add-on 'Simplify Curves', wich does exactly what i need (Reduce keyframes).
Unfortunately Simplify Curves does not seem to work with shape key animation curves. The option is just not available from the quick menu.

I am not that comfortable with python, so i can't tell if Simplify Curves is supposed to work on shape keys the way it does on other objects.

If you happen to know more, please let me know!
I am interested in any other tools/approaches for animation clean-up!

Thank you!

f.bra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplify f-curves operator has been created in a rigid way that only looks at the objects animation data. Not all animation data is stored in the one place, for example the shape key animation is stored as part of the mesh data, not as part of the object animation.

While some more work should be done to make the simplify f-curves a little more flexible, [this modified version](https://gist.github.com/sambler/49d84a74d841c877334342748d230614)(v1.0.4) allows the shape key f-curves to be simplified. You can download and unzip this version, then use the install addon from file button to select the unzipped py file, blender should then replace the existing addon with this version, if you have permissions to write over the file.